# UnicodeDecodeError в библиотеках Python & Flasky на русской виндовс

Tags: windows-7, unicode, flask

При попытке запуска фласки сервера (через консольный менеджер) выпадает: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: invalid continuation byte".

Ранее она же вываливалась при попытке установить зависимости приложения и Flask через pip, после долгих мытарств вылечил костылём отсюда: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4251

Add a solution here:
run a new cmd.exe console
chcp
it will show the system default code, for example 936.
open Lib/site-package/pip/compat/**init**.py
around 75 line, change return s.decode('utf_8') to return s.decode('cp936')
В моём случае значение было cp866.

Текущий стектрейс:

```
D:\project\Python\FlaskExample>venv\Scripts\activate
(venv) D:\project\Python\FlaskExample>manage.py runserver
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 111-448-424
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _boot
strap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\project\Python\FlaskExample\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.p
y", line 670, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "D:\project\Python\FlaskExample\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.p
y", line 564, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "D:\project\Python\FlaskExample\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.p
y", line 476, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __
init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in ser
ver_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: invalid
continuation byte
```

Фласки приложение для запуска взято с гит хаба (пример для книги, предположительно работает) miguelgrinberg/flasky, зависимости для окружения установлены из дев файла зависимостей.

Есть подозрение что он пытается вытащить какую-то системную строку которая содержит не юникод символы, но какую не представляю.

Имя пользователя с именем папки пользователя уже изменил на латинское написание, не помогло. Установка последней версии питона (3.6.2 x32)  тоже.

Можно ли что-то сделать с русскоязычной Windows 7 x64, что бы нормально заработал питон и фласк?

**Решение:**
В виндовс 7 есть 5 переменных представляющих систему, имя юзера, полное имя юзера, имя компьютера, полное имя компьютера, и имя рабочей группы, и для корректной работы питона они все должны содержать только латинские символы.

Однако проблему с установкой пакетов через pip это не решило, и мне всё ещё необходимо править функцию самого пипа по описанному алгоритму в каждом новом окружении.

Если есть идеи что ломает в русской винде его буду признателен.
(chcp 65001 в консоли pip не лечит(

Comment: Замените картинку с трейсом нормальным текстом.

Comment: Просто измените имя компьютера и рабочей группы на латиницу и не создавайте виртуальных окружений в каталогах имеющих кириллические символы в пути.

Comment: Да, это и помогло, но пип по прежнему нужно доправлять руками, как в окружениях (только с латинским путём), так и в основном питоне.